# Classify/categorize razor pages based on common group or interface name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

```
@page
@inherits @IFileProcess
@using Web.Helper 
@model Web.Pages.FileProcessModel
```

Is there a way to categorize razor pages. For example, in the code above I have the page inherit the IFileProcess interface.

Can I then, in a class get all the pages that inherit this interface?

Or is there a better way to specify which page belongs to which category (for example say - admin pages, general pages, user pages)

And then get the page names based on the category name?

Comment: Please convert the image to a code snippet

Comment: Typically folders are used to group like pages. So Admin pages are in a \admin folder. Use shared layouts or razor components for shared content between different pages;

Answer (score 0):

> Classify/categorize razor pages based on common group or interface
> name

You can use Areas in ASP.NET Core Razor page application.

Razor Pages expects to find areas located in a folder named Areas, which needs to be created manually in the root of the application. Each folder within the Areas folder represents a specific area. Razor pages within an area must be placed in a folder named Pages. For example, right click the project and add the folder with the following folder name and structure. It will create Administration and Production areas, then add an Index.cshtml file added to each area:

[image]

The Index.cshtml content as below:

```
@page
@model netcoreRazor.Areas.Production.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
} 

<h2>Production Index page</h2>
```

Then, we can use the following links to navigate to the Index page in each area:

```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Adminstration" asp-page="/Index">Adminstration</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Production" asp-page="/Index">Production</a>
    </li>
```

Screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information about using Areas, check the following articles:

[Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Working with Areas in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/areas)

[Areas In Razor Pages](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/324/areas-in-razor-pages)

Comment: Thank you. But my question is how do I programatically get the list of areas and pages under each area.